# Cannot install ApiDemos sample project on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I created ApiDemos project using Eclipse - New Project - Sample command. Trying to execute it on Android emulation, I got installation error. Then I opened data/app directory in the File Explorer, DDMS, and removed two files with name starting from ApiDemos (possibly this was incorrect, but this is done already). Now, trying to execute my ApiDemos project, I have:

```
[2011-11-15 16:23:19 - ApiDemos] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE
[2011-11-15 16:23:19 - ApiDemos] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-11-15 16:23:19 - ApiDemos] Launch canceled!
```

LogCat:

```
package com.example.android.apis signatures do not match the previously installed version, ignoring!
```

Is it possible to correct this now? I know that I can re-create emulator, but I would like to solve this problem with existing emulator, just to know how it should be done.

Comment: check emmulator API level and project API level..?

Comment: "Wipe user data" did the trick, though it is not exactly what I wanted, this is actually recreating the simulator (not something that I can do on real device :). Correct way to remove existing application was: adb uninstall com.example.android.apis Thanks.

Comment: @Padma Kumar - post this as answer to accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

uninstall the previous api demos by your adb command

```
adb -e uninstall com.example.android.apis
```

which installed in your emulator.

or try wipe user data while launching the emulator.

Comment: with devices we should remove the option -e

Answer (score 4):

First uninstall your application from the emulator:

adb -e uninstall your.application.package.name

Then try to install the application again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, with nexus 5 phone, the following command worked:

```
adb uninstall <Your_App_Package_Name>
```

so for your case, where package name is 'com.example.android.apis'

```
adb uninstall com.example.android.apis
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to go to the application manager. 
Navigate to the "All" tabs and scroll down to the bottom. 
Select the application and then from the menu select - uninstall for all users.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try 'uninstallAll' gradle task to uninstall the app completely