# Android SDK not properly installed error when I'm trying to build the apk file for a game I'm developing trough Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, build-error

Every time I try to build my APK file to export onto my android device, Unity gives me an error message stating that it was unable to build the apk file and that I should make sure the Android sdk is properly configured. However, I have reinstalled the latest sdk multiple times trough Oracle or Android studio but I keep getting the same error messages. I can test the game just fine in the Unity editor but get problems every time I try to export. It also states in the preferences under external tools that I'm not using the proper android sdk tools and ndk tools however like I said I've tried installing the proper ones multiple times even going so far as to reinstall everything but I keep on getting the same errors.

Does someone possibly know what I should do?

This is the error message I get when opening the project in the Unity editor:

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Android\build-tools'.
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError (System.Int32 errorCode, System.String maybeFullPath) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[TSource].HandleError (System.Int32 hr, System.String path) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[TSource].CommonInit () (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[TSource]..ctor (System.String path, System.String originalUserPath, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption, System.IO.SearchResultHandler`1[TSource] resultHandler, System.Boolean checkHost) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.CreateFileNameIterator (System.String path, System.String originalUserPath, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean includeFiles, System.Boolean includeDirs, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption, System.Boolean checkHost) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames (System.String path, System.String userPathOriginal, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean includeFiles, System.Boolean includeDirs, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption, System.Boolean checkHost) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
System.IO.Directory.InternalGetDirectories (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories (System.String path) (at <23c160f925be47d7a4fd083a3a62c920>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.FindLatestBuildTools () (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.UpdateToolsDirectories () (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools..ctor (System.String sdkRoot) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.CreateAndroidSDKTools (System.String rootDir) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.GetInstance[T] (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools+InstanceCreator creator) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.GetInstance () (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.SDKManager..ctor () (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.SDKManager.GetInstance () (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidPreferenceWindowExtension.WritePreferences () (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
UnityEditor.PreferencesProvider.WritePreferences () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/PreferencesWindow/PreferencesSettingsProviders.cs:753)
UnityEditor.PreferencesProvider.ApplyChangesToPrefs (System.Boolean force) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/PreferencesWindow/PreferencesSettingsProviders.cs:472)
UnityEditor.PreferencesProvider.ShowExternalApplications (System.String searchContext) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/PreferencesWindow/PreferencesSettingsProviders.cs:347)
UnityEditor.PreferencesProvider.OnGUI (System.String searchContext, System.Action`1[T] drawAction) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/PreferencesWindow/PreferencesSettingsProviders.cs:298)
UnityEditor.PreferencesProvider+<CreateExternalToolsProvider>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 (System.String searchContext) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/PreferencesWindow/PreferencesSettingsProviders.cs:201)
UnityEditor.SettingsProvider.OnGUI (System.String searchContext) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Settings/SettingsProvider.cs:103)
UnityEditor.SettingsWindow.DrawControls () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Settings/SettingsWindow.cs:322)
UnityEditor.SettingsWindow.DrawSettingsPanel () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Settings/SettingsWindow.cs:313)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event evt, UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 parentTransform, UnityEngine.Rect clippingRect, System.Boolean isComputingLayout, UnityEngine.Rect layoutSize) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/IMGUIContainer.cs:298)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event e, UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 worldTransform, UnityEngine.Rect clippingRect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/IMGUIContainer.cs:483)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event e) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/IMGUIContainer.cs:466)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/IMGUIContainer.cs:447)
UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy.DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/Events/MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy.cs:93)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/EventDispatcher.cs:280)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel, UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode dispatchMode) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/EventDispatcher.cs:156)
UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel.SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase e, UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode dispatchMode) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/Panel.cs:189)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel panel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/UIElementsUtility.cs:255)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/UIElementsUtility.cs:78)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)
```

> ```
> This is the error message I get after the apk build and run has failed:
> ```

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to install APK to device. Please make sure the Android SDK is installed and is properly configured in the Editor. See the Console for more details.
    C:/Users/mauri/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s "2245120c5e0d7ece" install -r "C:\Users\mauri\Desktop\Ball Tap\ball tap.apk"

    stderr[
    adb: failed to install C:\Users\mauri\Desktop\Ball Tap\ball tap.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.BallTap.Momo signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
    ]
    stdout[
    Performing Streamed Install
    ]
    exit code: 1
    UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.ADB.RunInternal (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.ADB.Run (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice.Exec (System.String[] command, System.String errorMsg) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice.Install (System.String apkfile) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+<UploadAPK>c__AnonStorey3.<>m__0 () (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.UploadAPK (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice device, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+LaunchProgressTaskManager taskManager) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension+<LaunchBuildOnTarget>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__2 () (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.ProgressTaskManager.Run () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/ProgressBarUtils.cs:71)
    UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.LaunchBuildOnTarget (UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.IDeploymentTargetsMainThreadContext context, UnityEditor.BuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetId targetId, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler progressHandler) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetManager.LaunchBuildOnTarget (UnityEditor.BuildProperties buildProperties, UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetId targetId, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler progressHandler) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/DeploymentTargets/DeploymentTargetManager.cs:45)
    UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer+<LaunchOnTargets>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:203)
    UnityEditor.ProgressTaskManager.Run () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/ProgressBarUtils.cs:71)
    UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.LaunchOnTargets (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] launchTargets) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:222)
    UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Launch (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.LaunchPlayer (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildLaunchPlayerArgs args) (at <252f3c2244e6415190676e82842416b7>:0)
    UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Launch (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget buildTarget, System.String path, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:166)
    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Answer (score 0):

1/ Android SDK

In your first output, it looks like your paths are not correctly set up. Have you checked that the path 'D:\Android\build-tools' exists ?

Normally, a regular install using Android Studio would install the SDK to

`c:\Users\<YOUR USER>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

In Unity, you can set this path up in Unity by going to Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools, and setting up the Android SDK path.

2/ Android SDK Version

Make sure that the version of the SDK you are targeting in Unity (Player Settings -> Other Settings -> Minimum API Level and Target API Level) is the same as the SDK you downloaded using Android Studio.

3/ Be careful of paths that have spaces or irregular characters

Especially on windows, this tends create a lot of problems in the Android build process. If you can avoid it, I'd recommend it.

4/ Package name and signatures

Your second error says 'signatures do not match previously installed version'. You probably already have an installed version on your device, signed with a different key. You need to completely remove the app on the device to resolve this problem. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489567/manually-installing-an-updated-apk-fails-with-signatures-do-not-match-the-previ).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and error didn't go away even if I set up the sdk correctly.
Here is how I solved it:
go to Settings->Apps in your phone. Uninstall the app (the name of the app should be Momo, I guess). Then try building from unity again, now it should work