# Package xxx.xxx.xxx signatures do not match previously installed version;

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After changing my PC and publishing a new release I got this error on Logcat when I was trying to install the app and the app not installed 
I know this is signing issue and I have to uninstall the app and reinstall in again this is not acceptable in my case because we have many users for the app

Can you please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signatures do not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489567/manually-installing-an-updated-apk-fails-with-signatures-do-not-match-the-previ?lq=1), also, try checking your signing key. Previous apk must have been signed with different signing key.

Comment: It does not matter for signed apk because you will use same signin key as previous.

Comment: I don't have the previous key

Comment: Do you forget the username and password for the key or  you no longer have the .keystore file？

Comment: If it is the former, it can be retrieved according to the .keystore file. If it is the latter, it is a pity that the new apk has to be packaged with the new key