# React-Native-CLI & Android :Failed to start the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up

Tags: android-emulator, react-native, react-native-cli

I can't run an existing react-native-cli app into my android device.
Similar thing happened for iOS emulator, but I'm managed to solve it.
So now I can only run into iOS not android. Please take a look at the error message and tell me what to do.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.banana.apple signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Unable to install C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Materials\Source Code\PunreachAPP\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
```

Comment: You can delete the app installed already in your device and build again as the signatures are not matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have installed the app previously ( possibly from the play store ) with a different version code and version name.
So in order to build and run the app, you need to uninstall the previously installed app with package id

> *com.banana.apple*

You can do this in 2 ways:

1. Manually uninstalling just like any other app from your device
2. Run the following command when connecting your phone via USB ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489567/manually-installing-an-updated-apk-fails-with-signatures-do-not-match-the-previ/31489883#31489883)).

> adb uninstall "com.banana.apple"

Comment: Could you change the package id to `com.banana.apple`? Cus this id is personal to me.